# Proper way of storing images related with project

Tags: java, database, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

One of features of project which i'm writing is to upload images and use it on pages. I know that we've got a lot of ways to handle it, but i'm really considered what is the most proper way.
Should I save byte array of image in database? Or maybe store images on other server, and in database only have their names and location? How are u doing it in your projects? When i was storing images in db, it's size has grown up to hundreds of gb (ofc after long time :)).

My current project is in spring boot and mongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most proper way is to store your image on a file system or cloud provider *([aws s3](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/) for example)*, and to link them in you database.

Answer (score 0):

There are n number of ways to save image because basically every image is a byte data.

```
1.Third party cloud services
2.File handling
3.Database storage
```

Comment: As i told i know about it. But my question was "what is the most proper way".

Comment: Third party cloud services